# Rails 5 dots issue in controller cannot be resolveed from newbee

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new bee in rails and trying to figure out how to pass id using custom controller but it look a blocker to me.

below is code of controller :

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @upload = Upload.new
    @uploadimage = Upload.all
  end

  def home

  end

  def destroy

  end
end
```

below is the index.html.erb file

```
<h1>Upload#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/upload/index.html.erb</p>

<%= form_for(@upload, url: "/uploads/home", :html => {:class => 'dropzone'} ) do |f| %>
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
<% end %>


<h3>Uploaded images</h3>
<% @uploadimage.each do |image| %>
    <% if !image.nil? %>
        <%= image_tag("/images/#{image.name}",style: 'height:100px; width:100px;') %>
        <%= link_to "delete #{image.name}", uploads_url(image) %>

    <% else %>
        <p>No images are present in db</p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

below is routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get "uploads", to: "uploads#index", via: :get
  get "uploads/:id", to: "uploads#destroy", via: :get
  get "uploads/index/:id", to: "uploads#destroy", via: :get
  get "uploads/index/", to: "uploads#index", via: :get

  root "uploads#index"
end
```

how to pass id to destroy/home action as i m getting id as dot instead of slash

Comment: are you trying to delete uploaded images?

Comment: yes for deleting the object we need id of the image

Comment: What do you mean "getting id as dot instead of slash"?

Comment: i m getting url like uploads/destroy.1 instead of  uploads/destroy/1

Comment: First of all destroy action have always `delete` method, and in link_to tag you should also define `method: :delete` for delete action.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using custom routes, if rails providing RESTful routes using `resources`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :uploads 
 root "uploads#index"
end
```

Edited:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :uploads, :controller => "custom_controller" 
 root "uploads#index"
end
```

This will manage all 7 action, and check `rake routes` for path for this all 7 action.

Comment: Thanks ashwin for your reply your code works well but what happen in those scenario where i have to define custom controller how to resolve those scenario in rails

Comment: Which controller?